# Hive Create Failed : Resource Not Available Exception

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapr

I am trying to create table in hive but it is giving me a below exception.

```
2015-08-20 22:47:12,145 INFO  [main]: exec.DDLTask (DDLTask.java:createTable(4074)) - Default to LazySimpleSerDe for table test_s
2015-08-20 22:47:12,157 ERROR [main]: exec.DDLTask (DDLTask.java:execute(478)) - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.IOException Error: Resource temporarily unavailable(11), file: test_s, user name: mapr, ID: 5000)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:620)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4189)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1093)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:916)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:906)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.IOException Error: Resource temporarily unavailable(11), file: test_s, user name: mapr, ID: 5000)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_with_environment_context_result$create_table_with_environment_context_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:24255)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_with_environment_context_result$create_table_with_environment_context_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:24223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_with_environment_context_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:24149)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_create_table_with_environment_context(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:893)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.create_table_with_environment_context(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:879)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:555)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:89)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.createTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:614)
        ... 20 more

2015-08-20 22:47:12,157 ERROR [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(545)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.IOException Error: Resource temporarily unavailable(11), file: test_s, user name: mapr, ID: 5000)
```

Did anyone faced such issue? Just to give more information I am using MapR cluster and looking at MapR management UI , everything seems to be normal.

Any idea?

Comment: have u check what metastore log is saying??? the same can be found in /tmp/{user}/hive.log location.... to confirure metastore you can check ans part

Comment: MetaStore service is running.As I am using MapR therefore I can see status as Running on MapR UI. Above log I have pasted from hive.log which is stored at different location in case of MapR. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

have you check the status of Metastore Service of hive, is the metastore configure and running?????  Also the Hive Service/thrift service should be running in the Node.
to Configure Meta Store Service. below update required in hive-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://myhost/metastore</value>
  <description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>mypassword</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://<n.n.n.n>:9083</value>
  <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
</property>
```

If You  are using MySQL as Backend DB for Hive, for more details. you check [Link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html) which helps to get more details of configuration.
Hope these will help.